# How can I mix [ ] single brackets and [[ ]] double brackets in the same if?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I can't make this piece of code that uses single and double brackets work:

```
if [ ! $# == 1 ] && ! [[ $1 =~ ^[-]?[0-9]$ ]];
then exit 1
fi
```

How can I mix both single and double types in the same expression?
Thanks.

Comment: You probably meant `if [ "$#" -ne 1 ] || ! [[ $1 =~ ^-?[0123456789]$ ]]; then exit 1; fi` which can also be written `if [[ $# -ne 1 || ! $1 =~ ^-?[0123456789]$ ]]; then exit 1; fi`. Or in standard sh: `case $#:$1 in (1:[0123456789] | 1:-[0123456789]) ;; (*) exit 1; esac`

Comment: The expression works fine but there is no valid reason to mix these.

Comment: Way easier indeed @StéphaneChazelas!! I am still learning bash.. Thank you. That was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, with your help, I found a piece of code that works for my needs, no if needed. I used the following line:

`[[ ! $# == 1 || ! $1 =~ ^-?[0-9]$ ]] && exit 1`

Thank you all.

Comment: Beware `[0-9]` is not always the same as `[0123456789]` (can include a lot more characters that happen to also sort between 0 and 9 in some locales) so is best avoided for input validation.